# XamlReader.Parse doesn't seem to be working with HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate, xamlreader

I'm trying to load the foillowing xaml:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Tag="{Binding Champ1}" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked">
        <CheckBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock Background="{Binding Path=Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}" Text="{Binding Champ1}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </CheckBox.Template>
    </CheckBox>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

using this in the constructor of my treeview:

```
string template = "<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource=\"{Binding Items}\">" +
                    "<CheckBox Checked=\"CheckBox_Checked\"" +
                              " Tag=\"{Binding Champ1}\"" +
                              " Unchecked=\"CheckBox_Unchecked\">" +
                        "<CheckBox.Template>" +
                            "<ControlTemplate>" +
                                "<TextBlock Background=\"{Binding Path=Background," +
                                                                "RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}\"" +
                                           "Text=\"{Binding Champ1}\" />" +
                            "</ControlTemplate>" +
                        "</CheckBox.Template>" +
                    "</CheckBox>" +
               " </HierarchicalDataTemplate>";

this.ItemTemplate = (HierarchicalDataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(template);
```

I'm getting this error:

> 'Impossible de créer le type inconnu 'HierarchicalDataTemplate'.'
>   numéro de ligne '1' et position de ligne '2'.

(My machine being configured in french, this message means : "Unable to create the unknown type HierarchicalDataTemplate").

Does someone have an idea why ?
The xaml snippet works perfectly when written directly in the xaml file.

Thanks !

---

## Edit

I had a test with a simple version:

```
string template = "<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource=\"{Binding Items}\">" +
                                "<TextBox Text=\"Test\"/>"+
                            " </HierarchicalDataTemplate>";
```

and the problem is the same.

---

## Edit2

Ok the problem is wider and seems unrelated to the `HierarchicalDataTemplate'

```
string test = "<TextBox Text=\"Test\" />";
var ret = XamlReader.Parse(test);
```

Produces the same error...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the problem(s).

As [John Bowen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/255294/john-bowen%20John%20Bowen) sait, the first problem are the event handlers wich can't be processed.
The second problem is that the main namespace is missing in the xaml.

So this code works:

```
string template = "<HierarchicalDataTemplate  xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" ItemsSource=\"{Binding Items}\">" +
                    "<CheckBox Tag=\"{Binding Champ1}\" >" +
                        "<CheckBox.Template>" +
                            "<ControlTemplate>" +
                                "<TextBlock Background=\"{Binding Path=Background," +
                                                                "RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=CheckBox}}\"" +
                                           " Text=\"{Binding Champ1}\" />" +
                            "</ControlTemplate>" +
                        "</CheckBox.Template>" +
                    "</CheckBox>" +
               " </HierarchicalDataTemplate>";

this.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Parse(template);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use event handlers with `XamlReader` because they are required to be located in the XAML's code-behind, which obviously doesn't exist in parsed XAML.

Comment: I just tested removing the handlers, and the error message is still the same.

Comment: In fact I also tested using a simpler version : `string template = "<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource=\"{Binding Items}\">" +
                                "<TextBox Text=\"Test\"/>"+
                            " </HierarchicalDataTemplate>";` and it stills fail with the same error message.